# parse variables file in Python

Tags: python, templates, definition

I wish to send Python script a definition file (with key and value pairs) which it should translate into an html table using templates.

For example:
say that the definitions file  def.txt contain the following lines:

```
build number: 5513
build date: 12/09/2011
```

I want it to be able to read it easily (iterate on each line) and create a data table.
something like:

```
<tbl>
   <tr> <td> build number </td> <td> 5515 </td> </tr>
   <tr> <td> build date </td> <td> 12/09/2011</td> </tr>
</tbl>
```

I want it to work for N lines in definition file. I don't care about the definition file format...

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Or.

Comment: I will suggest to read a little about python `split` function. Also try to find how does `open(url, 'r').readlines()` iterator works. It's not hard, really. Try to itarate through all lines in your file and split the data into some list. Then iterate the list and add all the tables stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> l = [i.split(": ") for i in open("def.txt")] #read and parse the input
>>> l #here is what we got
[['build number', '5513'], ['build date', '12/09/2011']]
>>> with open("out.txt", "w") as f: #open the out file
...    f.write("<tbl>\n") 
...    for k, v in l: #iterate and write
...         f.write("<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>\n".format(k, v)) 
...    f.write("</tbl>\n")
```

Comment: Won't the first statement leave the file opened?

Comment: @rplnt, we aren't assigning it to anything, so it should be garbage collected.

Comment: It's still a bad idea. Someone wants 4x performance boost by running your code under PyPy? Ooooops, suddenly you leak files everywhere. Even the CPython documentation advises not to rely on refcounting for cleanup.

Comment: @delnan, I didn't know this, thanks. I found it in PyPy documentation. But couldn't found in CPython docs. Can you give me a link?

Comment: Sadly, I didn't find anything absolutely explicit, only several places that strongly advice using `with` over leaving the reference lingering: http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html?highlight=python%20implementations#exceptions http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#predefined-clean-up-actions

Answer (score 1):

[config](http://www.red-dove.com/config-doc/) module